# Uninstalling device from USB port or refreshing USB drivers

Tags: usb, android

Currently when I plug my Android in via USB port 1, it registers as my tethered 4G internet access, and when I plug it via USB port 2, it registers as a debugging android development device that I can see in Eclipse.

Is there anyway to fix this? I'm really tired of switching it between ports.

If you know the answer to this, I am forever grateful :)

Running OS Windows 7 x64

Comment: What's the host OS?

Comment: windows 7 x64 OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Go to add/remove programs. Remove the Samsung Keis driver. This fixed it.